# open firewall popup to unlock C# app

Tags: wcf, firewall

I want unlock my c# on windows firewall(Win7/Vista), opening windows security alert to add a firewall execption to exception list. I'am using the ServiceHost to running my WCF service on a console app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Netsh AdvFirewall to open the ports you want or to allow the program in/out:

See here for documentation on Netsh AdvFirewall: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(WS.10).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Some samples:

**Enable a Program**
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”My Application” dir=in action=allow program=”C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe” enable=yes

**Open TCP port 16240**
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyOpenPort" protocol=TCP dir=out localport=16240 action=allow

Comment: Thaks for our help! And sorry for delay